# WPF and thumbnail

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to this concept but I'm sure there should be solution to it. I'm storing a design (a series of lines and shapes) as XML, also can save/load the drawing into/from XML file.
Now, new idea is:

1) How to show a thumbnail of the drawing such could be placed on a toolbar or panel (as toolbox)

2) By dragging/dropping of this thumbnail on a canvas it will open and show the drawing.

Comment: Patrick, thanks for adding WPF to my thread ... for some reasons I forgot to add that up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know more about `"ViewBox"` that is made for thumbnail things and it has many other usages. You can give it any WPF contents and it will do the thumbnail thing by some specific options.

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for sharing this idea. I have never head of it.

Comment: It has a simple concept. You should set the `"ViewPort"` property and simply set the WPF content of the control. It will rock your thumbnail world in WPF! ;D